# Best efficent way to create a cros platform real time chat apps

Tags: php, jquery, chat, real-time

Can some one tell me a best way to create a real time chat apps like facebook. which work on any browser and also mobile device like facebook ?

Comment: What you're asking is the equivalent of "What is the best way to build a house?". Too broad.

Comment: facebook is not a mobile device... @SecondRikudo the question is broad, but you could try to give an advice in which direction he should look or what he should alter to turn this into a better question

Comment: @RichardBernards I could, but then, so could you. Also, I have no intention of spoon-feeding someone who can't bother dividing the subject into smaller requirements, or even a simple Google search. I have better things to do with my time. If you want to teach someone how to Google, be my guest.

Comment: @SecondRikudo as you can see, I have given an answer with some research material...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading into the [XMPP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). You can implement this protocol on different platforms.